# Inverter battery charging

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, continuity

**If I connect a battery charger to my inverter AC output to charge the inverter's battery ,can I get a continuous power supply?**

Comment: If I understand the question, then the answer is no. The efficiency of the battery charger is less than 100 percent. The efficiency of the inverter is also less than 100 percent. So the battery will run down over time.

Comment: Certainly not. Do you mean DC input?

Comment: You're proposing a Free Energy device, a form of [Perpetual Motion Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion). These are not physically possible, at least not in this universe.

Comment: Bootstrapping?!

Answer (score 3):

A simple example:

- Inverter is 80% efficient.
- Battery charger is 90% efficient.
- Battery charger is charging at 100 W.
- Battery charger is drawing 100 / 0.90 = 111 W from the inverter.
- Inverter is drawing 111 / 0.80 = 139 W from the battery.
- End result? Battery is losing 39 W.

Remember that all this is without connecting an actual load. You have just made a very expensive heater.

Your idea is similar to other people's ideas of charging an electric car's battery using dynamos on the wheels. They don't realise that it takes energy to turn the dynamos. You wouldn't be able to patent your idea because, as a perpetual motion machine, it voilates the laws of thermodynamics.

Always remember that because of energy losses you can't win. You can't even break even!